# What does set -u do in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I've seen bash shell scripts which have this before some other commands

```
set -u
```

What does it do?  I can't seem to find any documentation on it.

Comment: have a look at `help set`

Comment: "[man bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)" and see the section under "`set`" for more information.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
-u  Treat unset variables as an error when substituting.
```

You can give this page a try :

[Set Man Page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/seth.html)

Comment: Or the [POSIX specification of `set`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) (which has a more complete description of the `-u` option).

Comment: Would it also fail with a default value?